# $f,g$ diffirentiable function at point $(x_0, y_0)$ how to show that $fg$ diffirentiable function at point $(x_0, y_0)$?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I guess there is pretty simple way of showing the statement below.. I tried using definition but it seem complicated.

> Suppose $f, g: \Bbb R^{2} \to \Bbb R$.  Prove if $f, g$ are differentiable at $(x_{0}, y_{0})$, then the product, $fg$, is differentiable at $(x_{0}, y_{0})$.

Comment: yes. $fg(x,y) = f(x,y) * g(x,y)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$fg=\frac {(f+g)^2-(f-g)^2}{4}$

Comment: that's nice identity .. but how do you know that if $h$ is differentiable so do $h^2$ ? or I'm missing something. in other words how do you know $(f+g)^2$ is differentiable ?

Comment: @d_e You can prove that easily if you have the chain rule at your disposal (the proof of the chain rule is not hard).  Since $g(x) = x^{2}$ is differentiable with derivative $2x$, and $f(x)$ is differentiable, then $g \circ f = f^{2}$ is differentiable with derivative $2f \cdot f'$, by the chain rule.

Comment: No we are talking about 2 variables here.  the existence of the partial derivative does not promise the function  differentiable.

Comment: @d_e I don't understand your last comment.  I was explaining why if $h$ is differentiable, $h^{2}$ is differentiable.

Comment: @user46944, using the chain rule I can get the partial derative. $g_x$ and $g_y$ . but yet...the fact that I have those does not mean the function is differentiable. I can give you a function with partial deratives which is not  differentiable.

Comment: @d_e You're right.  But I'm not talking about partial derivatives.  If the total derivative of $f$ exists, and the total derivative of $g$ exists, and the codomain of $f$ is the domain of $g$, then you can use the chain rule to find that $(g\circ f)' = g'(f(x)) f'(x)$.  The proof of this fact is easy (google it if you don't know it).  So I was saying: $h: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ defined by $h(x) = x^{2}$ is differentiable. So if $f: \Bbb R^{2} \to \Bbb R$ has a total derivative, then so does $h \circ f = f^{2}$, and it is $2f \cdot f'$.

Answer (score 2):

For all $x$ and $h$ such that $x$ and $x+h$ are in the domain of differentiability of $f$ and $g$, we have
$$(fg)(x+h)=f(x+h)g(x+h)=\left(f(x)+\mathrm{d}f(x)(h)+o(h)\right)\left(g(x)+\mathrm{d}g(x)(h)+o(h)\right)$$
$$=f(x)g(x)+f(x)\mathrm{d}g(x)(h)+g(x)\mathrm{d}f(x)(h)+o(h)$$
and thus $fg$ is differentiable at $x$ and we have
$$\mathrm{d}(fg)(x)(h)=f(x)\mathrm{d}g(x)(h)+g(x)\mathrm{d}f(x)(h).$$

EDIT: for your purpose, $x=(x_0,y_0)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ and thus $h=(h_0,k_0)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ too.

Comment: I just can't grasp the move you made from the first line to the second line. I know we can say that if, for example, $f(x) = o(h)$, and $g(x) = o(h)$ than of course $fg(x) = o(h)$. but that is not the case here. in here you have $f(x) = t(x) + o(h)$ and $g(x) = s(x) + o(h)$, so you will end up with $fg(x) -fs(x) - tg(x) + ts(x)  = o(h)$ --> $fg(x) = fs(x) + tg(x) -ts(x) + o(h)$. but in you move, you go to $fg(x) = ts(x) + o(h)$. 
How ?

Comment: You have some terms like $f(x)\times o(h)$ and $\mathrm{d}f(x)(h)\times o(h)$ which are $o(h)$, i.e. after being divided by $\|h\|$, they all tend to $0$ as $\|h\|\to0$.

Answer (score 1):

It may simply your life a bit to prove that  $P(x,y) = xy$ is a differentiable function from $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$.  Also prove that the function $Q: \mathbb{R}^2 
\to \mathbb{R}^2$ given by $Q(x,y) = (f(x,y),g(x,y))$ is differentiable at $(x_0,y_0)$.  The function you are interested in is $P \circ Q$, which is differentiable by the chain rule.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are writing the product, I assume that both functions take value in $\mathbb{R}$.

What is the equivalent result of yours in 1 dimension? How would you prove it?

**Hint**:

In 1D : $(fg)' = f'g + fg'$

By definition of $\text{d}f$:

$f(x + h) = f(x) + \text{d}f(x).h + o(\lvert h \rvert)$

Comment: thanks. but still I cannot follow that.. the very existence of the partial derivatives of $fg$ does not promise  differentiablility.

Comment: I see no use of any partial derivative here

Answer (score 0):

We know that $f'(x,y):\mathbb R^{2}\rightarrow \mathbb R$ is defined by

$(h_{1},h_{2}) \mapsto h_{1}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y) +h_{2}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y)$ or $f'(x,y)\cdot \textbf h \equiv  {\triangledown }f(x,y)\cdot \textbf h $

and similarly for $g'(x,y)$.

Now fix $\textbf x =(x,y)$ and define $f_{1}=f-f(\textbf x)$; $g_{1}=g-g(\textbf x)$ so that

$\tag 1 f_{1}(\textbf x)=g_{1}(\textbf x)=0$

We also have

$\tag 2 fg=f_{1}g_{1}+g(\textbf x)f_{1}+f(\textbf x)g_{1}+f(\textbf x)g(\textbf x)$

And we know that there is a $K>0$ such that

$\tag 3 \vert f(\textbf x+\textbf y)-f(\textbf y)\vert \leq K\vert \textbf y\vert$

which follows directly from the definition of derivative. A similar result holds for $g$.

Now $\triangledown (f_{1}g_{1})(\textbf x):\mathbb R^{2}\rightarrow \mathbb R$ is the unique linear transformation that satisfies

$\left | \frac{f_{1}(\textbf x+\textbf y)(g_{1}(\textbf x+\textbf y)-f_{1}(\textbf x)g_{1}(\textbf x)-\triangledown (f_{1}g_{1})(\textbf x)\cdot \textbf y}{\textbf y} \right |\rightarrow 0$ as $\vert y\vert \rightarrow 0$.

But now, using $(1)$ we get

$\tag 4 \left | \frac{f_{1}(\textbf x+\textbf y)(g_{1}(\textbf x+\textbf y)-\triangledown (f_{1}g_{1})(\textbf x)\cdot \textbf y}{\textbf y} \right |\rightarrow 0$ as $\vert y\vert \rightarrow 0$.

Now, observe that $f_{1}(\textbf x+\textbf y)g_{1}(\textbf x+\textbf y)=(f(\textbf x+\textbf y)-f(\textbf x))(g(\textbf x+\textbf y)-g(\textbf x))$ so we can also apply $(3)$ to write

$\tag 5 \vert (f_{1}(\textbf x+\textbf y)(g_{1}(\textbf x+\textbf y)\vert \leq C\vert \textbf y\vert ^{2}$

Finally, combining $(4)$ and $(5)$ we may conclude that $\triangledown (f_{1}g_{1})(\textbf x)=0$ and now inspection of $(2)$ gives the result.